# PHP my_asort() and my_ksort()

Tags: php, asort, ksort

I'm working on this problem of sorting in php. 
I have to write my own sorting functions, using my_asort() and my_ksort() functions that do exactly the same as asort and ksort respectively.
However I'm not able to get the correct output (I'm new to php), hence any help on how to correct this, would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I typed up:

```
<?php


echo "Original Array<br><br>";
$member = array("Jack" => "55kg", "Bill" => "35kg", "Aaron" => "60kg", "Daniel" => "80kg" );



foreach ($member as $user => $weight) {
echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";

function my_asort($member)
    {
    $keys=array_keys($member);
    sort($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key)
        {
        $val=$member[$key];
        unset($member[$key]);
        $member[$key]=$val;
        }
    }

echo "Sorted By user <br><br>";
foreach ($member as $user => $weight) {
echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";

function my_ksort($member)
    {
    $keys=array_keys($member);
    sort($keys);
    foreach($keys as $key)
        {
        $val=$member[$key];
        unset($member[$key]);
        $member[$key]=$val;
        }
    }

echo "Sorted By weight <br><br>";
foreach ($member as $user => $weight) {
echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}

?>
```

This is what it displays: (It doesn't do any sorting, what am I doing wrong?)

```
Original Array

Jack = 55kg 
Bill = 35kg 
Aaron = 60kg 
Daniel = 80kg 


Sorted By user 

Jack = 55kg 
Bill = 35kg 
Aaron = 60kg 
Daniel = 80kg 

Sorted By weight 

Jack = 55kg 
Bill = 35kg 
Aaron = 60kg 
Daniel = 80kg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call your functions (or use the code without a function declaration). You just defined them inside your code.

So if you want to use them, you need to call them and your code will look like:

```
<?php

function my_ksort(&$member)
{
  $keys=array_keys($member);
  sort($keys);
  foreach($keys as $key)
  {
    $val=$member[$key];
    unset($member[$key]);
    $member[$key]=$val;
  }
}

function my_asort(&$member)
{
  $keys=array_keys($member);
  sort($keys);
  foreach($keys as $key)
  {
    $val=$member[$key];
    unset($member[$key]);
    $member[$key]=$val;
  }
}    

echo "Original Array<br><br>";
$member = array("Jack" => "55kg", "Bill" => "35kg", "Aaron" => "60kg", "Daniel" => "80kg" );
foreach ($member as $user => $weight) { 
  echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";

my_asort($member);
echo "Sorted By user <br><br>";
foreach ($member as $user => $weight) {
  echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}

echo "<br><br>";

my_ksort($member);
echo "Sorted By weight <br><br>";
foreach ($member as $user => $weight) {
  echo "$user = $weight <br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it makes more sense now. However when testing the code, it just sorts the names out but does not sort the weight :/ @peky

Comment: @Arpit I do not see any any difference between `my_ksort` and `my_asort` function in your code. So it's supposed to do the same thing. You must sort array values in the second approach.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems :

You are not using the functions you created :

```
my_asort($member);
my_ksort($member);
```

And you'll have to add a reference (`&`) on your array in the parameters since you are not returning anything but modifying arrays :

```
function my_asort(&$member)
function my_ksort(&$member)
```

(I didn't check if the results correspond to the actual `asort` and `ksort` functions, but since it looks like a school homework, I'm sure you will find out now that you have an output of your functions)

Answer (score 0):

You have not called methods anywhere in your code. You just provided the method definition but not calling.

Answer (score 0):

Build your array like this:

```
$member[] = array('name' => 'Jake', 'weight' => '54');
$member[] = array('name' => 'Bill', 'weight' => '35');
$member[] = array('name' => 'Daniel', 'weight' => '80');
```

Then use the function bellow:

```
$new_arr = array_sort($member, 'name', 'SORT_ASC');
$new_arr2 = array_sort($member, 'weight', 'SORT_DESC');

print_r($new_arr);
print_r($new_arr2);

function array_sort($array, $on, $order='SORT_ASC'){
    $new_array = array();
    $sortable_array = array();

    if (count($array) > 0) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
            if (is_array($v)) {
                foreach ($v as $k2 => $v2) {
                    if ($k2 == $on) {
                        $sortable_array[$k] = $v2;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $sortable_array[$k] = $v;
            }
        }

        switch ($order) {
            case 'SORT_ASC':
                asort($sortable_array);
            break;
            case 'SORT_DESC':
                arsort($sortable_array);
            break;
        }

        foreach ($sortable_array as $k => $v) {
            $new_array[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
    }

    return $new_array;
}
```

Comment: That approach seems a little different to what I was expecting. But I'll try your way out. Thanks for the help :) @radu